# Clarification on Tensor definition

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let i,j,k, represent distinct indices in the set of Natural Numbers.

From the definition of a tensor:

(1) $$e_i,_j,_k = -e_i,_k,_j = -e_j,_k,_i =-e_j,_i,_k =-e_k,_i,_j=-e_k,j,i$$

Also:

(2) if $$i=1, j=2$$ and $$k=3$$, such that:

$$e_1,_2,_3$$ $$= 1$$

(3) "If any two indices are interchanged the sign of the component of the tensor changes"

Doesn't (1) and (2) imply that $$e_3,_2,_1$$ $$= -1$$, and $$(3)$$ implies that $$e_3,_1,_2$$ $$= 1$$ (i.e. -(-1) = 1)?

But then $$e_3,_1,_2$$ $$=-1$$ according to (1)?

Comment: Even permutations of indices, give $+1$ and odd ones give $-1$. The number of permutations necessary to obtain $e_{312}$ from $e_{123}$ is two, because of $$e_{312}=-e_{132}=e_{123}=1$$

Comment: @HBR But doesn't that still imply $$e_312$$ = 1?, which still contradicts (1)?

Comment: I am not following. According to (1) you have $e_{123}= -e_{321}$, you have $e_{312} = 1$

Comment: Then your definition of the tensor is completely wrong according the third statement: "If any two indices are interchanged the sign of the component of the tensor changes". This statement with the fact that $e_{123} = 1$ must give the definition of the tensor $e_{ijk}$, with if $i=k, i=j, j=k$ $e_{ijk}=0$, the rest is superfluous.

Comment: @Nameless But according to (1), if i,j,k = 1,2,3 respectively, eijk=-ekij, therefore e123=-e312

Comment: @FDoe, isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: @Nameless " e123=−e321, you have e312=1 " - I am saying that e312 = **-1**, according to (1), since any permutation of 1,2,3 would be negative. Though I guess the definition is wrong.

Comment: @FDoe, sorry that's my typo. I meant $1 = e_{123} = -e_{321} = - 1$

Answer (score 1):

Are you working on the tensor analysis and $e_{i,j,k}$ just represent the Levi-Civita symbol? Then you could have a look at this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

in fact, you have:

$e_{i,j,k}=+e_{j,k,i}=+e_{k,i,j}=−e_{k,j,i}=−e_{j,i,k}=−e_{i,k,j}$

Comment: So I guess (1) is wrong, right?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the Wikipedia page. You could get all the essentials